# Receiving org.hibernate.ResourceClosedException "This TransactionCoordinator has been closed"

Tags: java, hibernate, servlets

I have a servlet, running on Tomcat 6, that uses Hibernate 4.1.6 and c3p0 0.9.1.2, and I am getting too much org.hibernate.ResourceClosedException, with the message "This TransactionCoordinator has been closed".

I've already checked that `beginTransaction()` and `rollback()` or `commit()` are done before the thread is reused by another call.

At hibernate.cfg.xml, I have

```
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://host/database</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">username</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.zeroDateTimeBehavior">convertToNull</property>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</property>
  <property name="show_sql">true</property>
  <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">1800</property>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>

  <!-- mappings start here -->
  ...
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

and I am using a HibernateUtil.java to create a static sessionFactory for my application and I use it to control my transactions:

```
public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.configure();
            ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();        
            SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
            return sessionFactory;          
        }
        catch (Throwable ex) {
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static void shutdown() {
        getSessionFactory().close();
    }

    public static void beginTransaction() {
        HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();
    }

    public static void commit() {
        HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().getTransaction().commit();
    }

    public static void rollback() {
        HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().getTransaction().rollback();
    }

}
```

When I start using the database in a servlet, my code is basically this:

```
    try {
        HibernateUtil.beginTransaction();

        // do stuffs

        HibernateUtil.commit();
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        HibernateUtil.rollback();
        throw e;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        HibernateUtil.rollback();
        throw e;
    }
```

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: in that "// do stuffs" did you try to get entity object from other transaction?

Comment: Thanks, I think I've found the problem, researching to answer you. There is some objects that I do `session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession()` and the session is a static property. This could be the problem?

Comment: yes, the Hibernate Session is not thread-safe. so you cant declare it in static property

Answer (score 0):

I have closed a session after completing transaction and in the new session i have used the object of previous session, this caused me an 'Transaction Coordinator has been closed'
I have edited the code to use new session object, now the error is resolved